# How to avoid attachCurrentThread exception when using pylucene in flask?

Tags: flask, pylucene

I built a simple wrapper service around a class that reads and queries a Lucene index using `pylucene` (6.5). I get the following error when running the server:

`RuntimeError: attachCurrentThread() must be called first`

I assume that the problem stems from the `lucene.initVM()` statement and I tried moving it in different places. It works if I put it in the request method, but that means I need to load the index with every request.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Calling lucene.getVMEnv().attachCurrentThread() before handling each request related to Lucene fixed it,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543987/4917303

Answer (score 0):

Putting the initialisation statement (in this case the constructor of `IndexHandler`) in a function with a `flask` decorator `@app.before_first_request` solves the problem.

```
@app.before_first_request
def load_index():
    global index_handler
    index_handler = IndexHandler()
```